# Pdf.js renders text inconsistently on canvas

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I have a fairly large AngularJS app. I've integrated [PDF.JS  simpleviewer.html code from the examples folder](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/components) inside my app(didn't modify it). When I use PDF.JS to render a single page within the container(not iframed), I get very inconsistent text rendering:

Original
[image: Original]
Inconsistent boldness
[image]
Inconsistent fonts
[image]

When I use the same pdf file with the examples code outside of my app, it always renders correctly. It's only when I integrate simpleviewer.html inside my app (not modifying a single line), that this issue appears.

Can you suggest what might be the root cause for it. Which areas should I look for conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that if I have multiple instances of the viewer on that same page, they will try to render pdfs all at the same time -> this causing the bad rendering of text. If there is just one instance, text renders fine.